# Does Flaw (Endurance) reduce health?

Tags: song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

So I understand that flaw gives you a -1D on all tests involving your chosen ability. And I hope I understand that it also affects passive results.

Let's say you have Endurance 3 and Flaw (Endurance) i'd say you have 6 health points. But the archetypes have really weird stats (including combat defense).

**Q: If you take Flaw (Endurance, Will) does it reduce your health/composure?**

**Q: If you take the Flaw (Agility, Athletics, Awareness, Cunning etc) does it reduce your combat/intrigue defense?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it does

On page 62:

> Your Endurance rank determines your Health, which equals 3 × Endurance.

In other words, if a flaw affects your Endurance rank, it affects your health too.

Flaws, in general, always affect your passive result (normally rank * 4), so all secondary abilities are affected by a flaw in that primary ability, including Combat Defense and Intrigue Defense.

> When you gain this drawback, select a single ability. You take –1D on all tests involving this ability. For how these flaws might manifest in your character, see the following chart. **When calculating your passive test result with this ability, you treat your ability as being 1 point lower**. For example, if you have Perception 4 and the Flaw (Awareness) drawback, your passive Awareness result would by 12 ([4 − 1] x 4). **You also reduce any derived characteristics (such as Intrigue Defense or weapon damage) by 1**.

That -1D denotes a **Penalty Dice** (page 31), which means you must subtract an additional dice from your checks. Example, you have *Marksmanship* 4 but also got *Flaw (Marksmanship)*, that means you roll 4 dice, but have to remove one dice from the result of your checks.

But keep in mind that penalties don't reduce derived stats, that is a wording exclusive to *Flaws*. So if you take a -1D penalty from wounds, your Health, Combat Defense or Intrigue Defense is unaffected, but on any check you will have to remove one dice from the result.

Comment: Does it also mean you can take 1 injury/wound less than your endurance value since the amount you can take is capped by your value?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect injury/wounds, as they are not checks nor derivated stats. Your actual Endurance rank is still *X* and not *X-1*.